# SQL Query to suggest Chairs

Tags: sql, oracle

i am working on trains Reservation with auto suggest chairs query

it's supposed to take trip Date ,from station ,to station and no of seats as bind variables and retrive chairs that are in sequence and not reserved.
for example : if chair 1,3 is reserved and chairs 2,4,5 not reserved and user enterd 2 seats , then query should suggest 4,5 and not 2,4

i'm trying to use `lead` or `lag` analyic functions

```
select * from 
(
    select row_number() over (order by seat_no) rno, seat_no,lag(seat_no,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY seat_no) lag , lead(seat_no,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY seat_no) lead 
    from TRAIN_LINE_DETAILS tld,train_lines tl
    where TRIP_DATE = to_date(:tipDate,'dd-mm-yyyy')            
    and tld.line_code =  tl.line_code
    and station_from =:sfrom 
    and station_to =:sto
    and  is_reserved = 0
)

where rno <= :n
--and lead-1 = seat_no or lag+1 = seat_no
```

output :
[output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2P5W.png)

Comment: Effectively you need islands of seats , See http://www.orafaq.com/node/2865

Comment: Your requirement seem not clear enough. If we have not reserved: `2, 4, 5, 11, 12, 13, 14, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35` and user enter **5** then what would we suggest? And what if `...14, 16, 31...` instead of `...14, 31,...`. And Your problem may need an algorithm to solve rather than simply by a complex query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any sample data or descriptions of your tables it is difficult to test but something like this:

```
SELECT seat_no
FROM   (
  SELECT seat_no,
         is_reserved,
         COALESCE( 
           LEAD( CASE is_reserved WHEN 0 THEN seat_no END )
             IGNORE NULLS OVER ( ORDER BY seat_no ),
           seat_no + 1
         ) AS next_reserved_seat
  FROM   TRAIN_LINE_DETAILS tld
         INNER JOIN train_lines tl
         ON ( tld.line_code =  tl.line_code )
  WHERE  TRIP_DATE    = to_date(:tipDate,'dd-mm-yyyy')            
  AND    station_from =:sfrom 
  AND    station_to   =:sto
)
WHERE  is_reserved = 0
AND    next_reserved_seat - seat_no >= :n;
```

This assumes that all the seats are enumerated in your table and each has an associated `is_reserved` flag which is `0` when the seat is not reserved. The query will go through all the seats looking for those where the seat and the `:n-1` subsequent seats are not reserved and will output the seat number at the start of the un-reserved range.